# MAUI - ResourceManager.GetString is throwing an exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: maui

I have ported the code of Xamarin app to .NET MAUI app. There are no compilation errors so I tried to run the app and check how it is working initially. Unfortunately I am getting **System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** '' .

Here is the **Appresource.Designer.cs** file where it is throwing the Error.

```
    internal class AppResources {
        
        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
        
        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;
        
        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal AppResources() {
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Appname.Resources.Strings.AppResources", typeof(AppResources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }
        
        
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Menu.
        /// </summary>
        internal static string basement_header {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("basement_header", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
```

Here is **App.xaml.cs
**

```
   public App()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       
       MainPage = new Views.FlyoutPageView { Detail = new NavigationPage(new dashboard()) };
   }
```

**FlyoutPageView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class FlyoutPageView : FlyoutPage

    public FlyoutPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuPageView.NavigationListView.ItemSelected += NavigationListView_ItemSelected;
    }

    private void NavigationListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem is MasterNavigationItem item)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.Target));
            menuPageView.NavigationListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }

}
```

**MenuPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MenuPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    }
```

**MenuPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:Appname.Resources.Strings"   
             Title="{x:Static strings:AppResources.basement_header}"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource darkBlueBS}"
             >
```

I might be using a deprecated code because I am not a Xamarin developer but not sure what to do now or why it is null because I have added the Strings value in AppResources.resx

1. Migrated Xamarin App code to .NET 8.
2. Removed old Xamarin packages which are not supported in MAUI.
3. I did convert MasterDetailsView page to FlyoutPageView before migrating because it was deprecated.
4. Migrated Xamarin.Android files.
5. The entry point is now changed to App.xaml so I can not compare and debug.
6. Turned on System.Exception otherwise it was throwing this error on FlyoutPageView InitializeComponent - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Which code caused this error? You said that you modified the AppResources.resx file. Did this cause this error?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT No, I do not think editing AppResources.resx caused the error. I am not able to use Localization Strings like Xamarin forms. I looked in MAUI and most of the settings are same. Some people say that turning System.Exception is causing this error but I can not turn off System.Exception because it is important for my debugging. Here is the github link of the same issue - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7443

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Xamarin. You can follow the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7443) up.

You can notice that this is a problem with Fast Deployment, where files like en-US/MyLibrary.resources.dll aren't deployed properly.

Here are some workarounds for you.

First, you can try to disable the Android "Fast deployment" options setting for the sample project.

[image]

Second, you can also uncheck `System.Exception` from Debug menu and this will make the project work.